# Traefik v2 and Invalid Lets Encrypt Certificate

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, traefik

I'm having issues with traefik generating the certificate after upgrading from traefik 1 to 2.
I'm using docker providers, and set up everything using labels.

Here is a link to the certificate test: https://check-your-website.server-daten.de/?q=staging.evopoints.co.za

The static `traefik.yml` config is:

```
global:
  checkNewVersion: true
  sendAnonymousUsage: false

providers:
  docker:
    exposedByDefault: false
    watch: true

entryPoints:
  web-insecure:
    address: ":80"

  web-secure:
    address: ":443"
    transport:
      lifeCycle:
        requestAcceptGraceTimeout: 42
        graceTimeOut: 42
      respondingTimeouts:
        readTimeout: 42
        writeTimeout: 42
        idleTimeout: 42

certificatesResolvers:
  letsencrypt:
    acme:
      email: <private-email>
      storage: acme.json
      caServer: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: web-insecure

api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true
  debug: true

log:
  filePath: /mnt/logs/traefik/traefik.log
  level: DEBUG

accessLog:
  filePath: /mnt/logs/traefik/access.log
```

Here are the relevant snippets from `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

  webapp:
    image: <private registry>
    restart: always

    volumes:
      ... snipped list of volumes ...

    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # Create a bunch of required middlewares
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.www-redirect.redirectregex.regex=^https://evopoints.co.za/(.*)"
      # Note: all dollar signs need to be doubled for escaping.
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.www-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=https://staging.evopoints.co.za/$${1}"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.webapp.headers.customrequestheaders.http-x-forwarded-proto=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.webapp.headers.sslredirect=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.webapp.headers.sslforcehost=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.webapp.headers.sslhost=staging.evopoints.co.za"

      # Insecure Entry
      - "traefik.http.routers.webapp-insecure.entrypoints=web-insecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.webapp-insecure.rule=Host(`staging.evopoints.co.za`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.webapp-insecure.middlewares=https-redirect"

      # Secure entry
      - "traefik.http.routers.webapp.entrypoints=web-secure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.webapp.rule=Host(`staging.evopoints.co.za`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.webapp.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.webapp.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.routers.webapp.middlewares=webapp"

  nginx:
    image: <private_registry>
    restart: always
    volumes:
      ... snipped volumnes ...
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.nginx.loadbalancer.server.port=443"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.entrypoints=web-secure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.rule=Host(`staging.evopoints.co.za`) && (PathPrefix(`/static`, `/media`) || Path(`/service-worker.js`))"

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./resources/traefik/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml
      - ./resources/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
      - ./logs/traefik:/mnt/logs/traefik
```

Comment: `caServer: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory` => you are using the staging infra of lets-encrypt. This is meant to test that your certs can be generated correctly without jeopardizing your quota on the production service. The certs created by staging are signed by a ROOT CA not part of any browser/root CA bundle and will therefore appear as invalid on automated test tools. See https://letsencrypt.org/docs/staging-environment/

Comment: `openssl s_client -showcerts -servername staging.evopoints.co.za -connect staging.evopoints.co.za:443` looks pretty OK to me (for a staging lets-encrypt cert).

Comment: I seemed to have issues with normal certs before I started using staging; But that was before I changed some bits of my compose file. I'll re-enable normal environment and test again. Thx for pointing this out @Zeitounator

Comment: Thank you @Zeitounator that now works. My understanding about staging was that it allows you to generate a lot more for testing etc. but didn't know that they would technically still be invalid. I just thought they would expire faster or something like that.

Comment: Production [https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-production-environment-wildcards/55578)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was as zeitounator pointed out, in comments of my post. The letsencrypt staging environment doesn't sign the certicates correctly, which is intended, and so appears invalid. Staging environment is merely meant to test that certs are in fact generated, that's all.

After changing to the production cert resolver, everything worked as intended.